# Creating a datadog dashboard using REST API

Tags: datadog

I am trying to create a dashboard in datadog using the REST API described here: http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#timeboards

Whatever I do, however, I keep getting a 400 response back with a message "Invalid JSON input". I have simplified my json to just a few required fields, and empty "graphs" section, and that still doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

`curl -i -X POST 'https://app.datadoghq.com/api/v1/dash?api_key=<key>&application_key=<the_key>' -d '{"dash":{"title":"Foo","description":"bar","graphs":[]}}'`

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 18:27:29 GMT
DD-POOL: dogweb_sameorig
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DD-VERSION: 34.34544
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 34
Connection: keep-alive

{"errors": ["Invalid JSON input"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `Content-Type` as a header with the request, as shown [in the docs](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=console#timeboards)

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" 'https://app.datadoghq.com/api/v1/dash?api_key=<key>&application_key=<key>' -d '{"dash":{"title":"Foo","description":"bar","graphs":[]}}'
```

Response:

```
{"errors": ["The parameter 'title' is required"]}
```

Your data is also not formatted according to the docs (there should be no `dash` field at the top level, for starters).

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" 'https://bnc-npr.datadoghq.com/api/v1/dash?api_key=abc'  -d '{"dash":{"title":"Foo","description":"bar","graphs":[]}}'...... still got same error : 
{"errors":["The parameter 'title' is required"]}